# How to make only a specific part of a website be affected by the parallax effect in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

So, I have a e-commerce website in which at the start I have Implemented parallax effect by following a tutorial {Link: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJTNCR75vc0}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJTNCR75vc0%7D), but I only need the main head to move by the parallax, instead of the whole webpage. So, that I can write content under the title. Rest is self explained by the code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  min-height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav img {
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  /* -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.8px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000; */
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #d44336;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

#welcome {
  color: #000;
}

#logo-img {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  outline: lightblue solid 5px;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.headline {
  font-size: 10vh;
  font-family: fantasy, cursive;
  color: lightcoral;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 0.4;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: royalblue;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
}

.headline::first-letter {
  font-size: 20vh;
}

.headline-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-headline {
  font-size: 5vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.img-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
  top: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 2000vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="sample.html"><img src="Images/trassical.jpg" alt="" id="logo-img">
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="sample.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="subscriptions.html">Subscriptions</a></li>
          <li><a href="featured.html">Featured</a></li>
          <li><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.html">Login/Signup</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </nav>
</section>
<section id="welcome">
  <video src="Images/synthwave.mp4" muted loop autoplay class="img-background"></video>
  <div class="headline-wrap">
    <h1 class="headline">Trassical's E - Shop</h1><br>
    <h2 class="sub-headline">Gaming accessories, merch and more!</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const parallax = document.querySelector('.img-background')
    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    parallax.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollPosition * 0.5 + 'px)';
  });
</script>
<section class="intro">
  <div class="game-codes">
    Discounted games
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

can use parent class for that particular part of website where you want parallax effect